# understand '' Widget build(BuildContext context) '' in flutter

Tags: flutter

in this code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hello Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Hello, Flutter!',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

i am confused that why  the function build define with widget class , but after that , it return MatrialApp class .
i know that material app is extends from widget, but in this example when we set matrialapp value , it cant change widget value , because MaterialApp is Inheritance from widget and cant change widget property.

my problem is  syntax of dart.

please give me some explain.
thanks.

my problem is  syntax of dart.

please give me some explain.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Widget build(BuildContext context) method is the most important method in a Flutter widget. It is called whenever the widget needs to be rebuilt, such as when the state of the widget changes or when the parent widget is rebuilt.

The BuildContext argument is a handle to the location of the widget in the widget tree. It can be used to access information about the widget's parent and children, as well as the overall state of the application.

The build() method must return a Widget. This widget will be the child of the current widget in the widget tree.

Comment: thanks.
but my problem is , how can MaterialApp 's constructor can set the widget property?
because materialApp is child of widget and cant change widget property.